# Join 4 tables with inner join on PostgreSQL (error : operator does not exist : integer = character)

Tags: mysql, postgresql, integer, character, varchar

I'm having a hard time trying to inner join 4 tables to determine the region of a warehouse based of the warehouse_id. I'm almost sure my logic is correct but I get an operator error while running the code (error operator does not exist : integer = character).

So the issue is that t1.location_id is an integer while t3.country_id is a character (for example 'US'). FYI all other id columns are integers. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Here's my query :

```
SELECT warehouse_name
FROM warehouses t1
INNER JOIN locations t2
    ON t1.location_id = t2.location_id
INNER JOIN countries t3
    ON t1.location_id = t3.country_id
INNER JOIN regions t4
    ON t1.location_id = t4.region_id
WHERE t4.region_id = 3;
```

Comment: Xou have to find out how the numeric `location_id`s and the `country_is`s are related.

Comment: Since you are saying location_id is integer, and country_id is character, you cannot equate them, your query fails at `ON t1.location_id = t3.country_id`. For your 2 letter country codes, do you have equivalent integer IDs in any other column, then you need to use that in your JOIN condition.